# Select same SUM from table and same column two different ids

Tags: mysql

i have a problem & I'm new in this.

i have a table called "items"
and there is IDs column and count column
also i got a characters table which are the owners of the items ids

i have here a code that working..and shows the top character with the item and its count..
to explain more..

```
"SELECT SUM(it.count) FROM characters ch  
LEFT OUTER JOIN items it ON ch.charId=it.owner_id
WHERE item_id=40001 ORDER BY SUM(it.count) DESC LIMIT 20");)
```

So what i want exactly is to make this takes a list of a second item id from same items table and same column count ...

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java or JavaScript (which are entirely different languages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, let me make your query a bit more readable:

```
SELECT SUM(it.count)
FROM characters ch 
LEFT OUTER JOIN items it ON ch.charId=it.owner_id 
WHERE item_id=40001 
ORDER BY SUM(it.count) DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

This query is a bit weird. First you are selecting *one* sum (you are not grouping by anything) then you are orderbing by that sum, and limiting the number of returned rows to *20*?

Also, you're doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but then using the outer table in your `WHERE` table, which results in all rows being removed that only have a character but no item.

The following query would do the exact same thing.

```
SELECT SUM(it.count)
FROM characters ch 
JOIN items it ON ch.charId=it.owner_id 
WHERE item_id=40001
```

Now if you want more than one item_id, you either want the total count of both:

```
SELECT SUM(it.count)
FROM characters ch 
JOIN items it ON ch.charId=it.owner_id 
WHERE item_id IN (40001,40002)
```

Or you want sums for each item

```
SELECT SUM(it.count)
FROM characters ch 
JOIN items it ON ch.charId=it.owner_id 
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY SUM(it.count) DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

You could change the JOIN to do just a few item types:

```
SELECT SUM(it.count)
FROM characters ch 
JOIN items it ON ch.charId=it.owner_id AND it.item_id IN (40001,40002)
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY SUM(it.count) DESC 
LIMIT 20
```